# How to undo a drag-and-drop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, undo

On a page for young kids, they have to drag-and-drop one of the 3 signs "<", "=" or ">" between 2 random numbers. This functions once.

After showing them whether they've got it right, I would like to automatically undo the drag-and-drop and display 2 new random numbers. That means sending the sign they chose back to its original position. Something like

```
WARNING FALSE CODE
move(document.getElementById("up3").innerHTML, document.getElementById("middle3").innerHTML);
```

My "up3" and "middle3" are divs of the type

```
<div class="up3" id="up3"></div>
```

The corresponding classes just deal with
positioning, borders and such like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On a page for young kids, they have to drag-and-drop one of the 3 signs "<", "=" or ">" between 2 random numbers. This functions once.

> After showing them whether they've got it right, I would like to automatically undo the drag-and-drop and display 2 new random numbers. That means sending the sign they chose back to its original position. Something like...

I can think of `3 ways` to do this

1. Hard reload the page:

   ```
   location.reload(true); // reload(false) reloads the browser cache
   window.location.reload();
   ```
2. Transfer all code/text inside `<div id="a">` into `<div id="b">`

   ```
   document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = document.getElementById("a").innerHTML; // transfer code line
   document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = null;
   ```

   or

   ```
   document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = document.getElementById("a").innerHTML; // transfer code line
   document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "<div>Empty state code-block</div>";
   ```
3. Finally (and more neat approach) create `reset()` js funciton called whenever you need to

   ```
   function reset(){
      document.querySelector("#answer-container").innerHTML = null;
      document.querySelector("#gt-container").innerHTML = ">";
      document.querySelector("#lt-container").innerHTML = "<";
      document.querySelector("#e-container").innerHTML = "=";
      document.querySelector("#gt-container").innerHTML = ">";
      // more code...
   }
   ```

I think you should re-state your problem into a bit more specific statement, I'm not really sure if my answer could get the result you desired.

Comment: Thank you Kyle Olodin. I'll try the reset function because I want to keep some stuff such as the number of successes vs. the number of failures. I think I was using the wrong keyword, writing ...innerHTML='' instead of ...innerHTML=null

Comment: yes sure pal :), I need some help here I am grinding for REPS, it would be wonderful to mark mine as an answer to your problem; just comment if any problem occurs in my solution.